# Duplicate display of annotation in SLD script

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sld

I am using one SLD file in GeoServer of village parcel display.  It works fine, but the issue is that the annotation(parcelno) display duplicates/replicates when I zoom in.

What can I do?

Comment: can you expand your question with more information - how are you displaying the map? may be some code, and a picture of the output would also be helpful

Comment: In sld file have code of displaying the label in <Textsymbolizer> tag but the displaying the lable in my map its show more than one when i zoomed in its displayed more than one time like 123 123 123 in one polygon. but i want to show only one 123

Comment: is the layer tiled?

Comment: yes it is, so what i will do?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have used tiling. Each request for a tile is a completely new request as far as the server is concerned, so it tries to label each polygon that appears in the requested map.

To solve this problem you can investigate the use of meta-tiling or make your labels a separate layer that is no tiled.